# How to create an empty GeoJSON template with several empty fields (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, geojson, template

I would like to know if it is possible to create a template in the GeoJSON file format. With a template I mean simply an empty GeoJSON with the field names already present such as in the example in the picutre.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save this on your disk and edit the field names with any text editor

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "jsontemplate",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "a1": "", "a2": "", "a3": "", "a4": ""}, "geometry": null }
]
}
```